# Model Dump Parser (like XGBFI) for LightGBM and CatBoost

Tags: python, xgboost, lightgbm, catboost

Currently my employer has multiple GLM in a live environment. I am interested in identifying new features and interactions to enhance the accuracy of these GLM; for now I am limited to the GLM structure so simply deploying a solution which automatically accounts for interactions is not possible.

I have in the past used XGBoost to identify powerful feature interactions through the use of `XGBFI` / `XGBFIR`. I am now looking in to using LightGBM and CatBoost to do the same but cannot seem to find a tool like `XGBFI` which works on those models.

**Question:** Does anything similar to `XGBFI` exist for LightGBM and CatBoost?

Answer (score 0):

Both LightGBM and CatBoost have functions that give you the models' feature importances. They are described in the respective docs here:

- **LightGBM**: [plot_importance](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.plot_importance.html#lightgbm-plot-importance) and [lightgbm.importance](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R/reference/lgb.importance.html)
- **Catboost**: has [get_feature_importance](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_get_feature_importance.html) which is described in more detail on its [concepts page](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/fstr.html)